# Django rest framework with multiple platforms

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, arduino

Hi all I have an arduino and android app I need to write data from arduino to database without authentication but if user wants to see data from android app he needs to be authenticated how can I do it thanks.

Comment: You could hard-code a password or login code in the arduino, though someone could reverse engineeer it to get the access token

Comment: Anybody can pretend to be an Arduino so there is no possible security measure solely based on platform

Comment: Is that the POST or GET method ?

Comment: Yes it is using POST in arduino and GET for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first find whether the request is coming from arduino or andriod.

To make that happen, if it is GET method from client side you have to pass something like,

app=arduino or app=android in query params.

If it is a POST method you can send in request body(app: "arduino").

So in Django views, can declare some list like,

**UN_AUTHENTICATED_METHODS = ['get_users']**

> get_users is a method

After that in your function,

```
if self.action in UN_AUTHENTICATED_METHODS and request.query_params.dict()["app"]=="arduino":
   return (permissions.AllowAny(),)
return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(),)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that must be what I need